# Embedding flv (flash) player in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, flv, embedded-flashplayer

I'm trying to the the flv Flash player [from here](http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=JW_FLV_Player) in a windows forms application. I currently have it playing 1 .flv file with no problems but I really need to be able to play multiple files. Has anyone had experienace of using the playlists that this control offers or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get the control to run the way you want it in a webpage/browser? If yes (and the problem is with winforms, I'd just embed it in a browser control. If no, I'd as the creators directly.

Answer (score 4):

I would be very hesitant to place the WebBrowser control between your software and the flv, because you will lose all control of the flv and will not get any meaningful notifications about its status. The lack of tight integration will lead to a very poor user experience. The blog post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/twalters/archive/2003/12/29/46265.aspx) has instructions on embedding flash via COM.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I ran into this same problem as well.  The prob is that loadmovie method doesnt seem to clear the last movie.  And so far I haven't found any technique to load a new movie into the same flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found myself needing to do the same thing and since there was no clear solution yet I figured I would provide mine. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
//Load JWPlayer swf
axShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars = "autostart=true";
axShockwaveFlash1.ScaleMode = 0;
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\JWPlayer\player.swf");
axShockwaveFlash1.Play();

//Play new flv
axShockwaveFlash1.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"sendEvent\" returntype=\"xml\">" + 
    "<arguments><string>load</string><string>" +
    @"C:\FLVFiles\Example.flv" +
    "</string></arguments></invoke>");
```

My primary reference for figuring this out was: (Look at last post)
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/8687/how-to-call-sendevent-from-c

I mention this primarily because there are links to other events that can be called which people might be interested in.