# Efficient data binding for Flash ActiveX hosted in .Net Forms (not asp.net)

Tags: c#, winforms, apache-flex

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533/embedding-flv-flash-player-in-windows-forms) asked about embedding a flash player in .net. The provided answer is to host the ActiveX Flash player on the form.

This works for simple things, like playing a flash movie. But what if you want to provide data hosted by the .net application to a flex application? Is there an efficient way to transport data from the .net application to the flex runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a web service with XML or JSON return vals, and/or you could pass query string data to the flex app via .net.

Comment: right, i've used that method. but the downside is serializing all the data into xml or json. I have these nice data structures in memory, so I was wondering if i could make in-memory references, instead of transmitting the data.