# How to play local Flv files through C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, flv

I'm having some local Flv files that i want to play in C# windows Form Application. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533/embedding-flv-flash-player-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.shareoffice.it/webmaster/archive/2006/07/01/6451.aspx