# Is the possible to run .flv file in window application?

Tags: .net

I want to play .flv file in window application.
During my analysis I found that when we want to run .flv file in window application it needs to call external API.
When I call external API and call below script but unable to find solution. It returns the error
“Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component”’

1)    `flashPlayer.CallFunction(" < invoke name=\"loadAndPlayVideo\" returntype=\"xml\" > < arguments > < string > " + videoPath + "< /string > < /arguments > < /invoke >`

2)    `flashPlayer.CallFunction("< invoke name=\"loadFLV\" returntype=\"xml\"> < arguments >  < string > " + videoPath + " < /string > < /arguments > < /invoke >");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533/embedding-flv-flash-player-in-windows-forms

Comment: [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533/embedding-flv-flash-player-in-windows-forms)!

Comment: @Brian: I don't know if I can trust you... can I see your certificate authority?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It's a trick! The link is already posted by emd...